# Frequency dependency of dielectric constant

Tags: dielectric

The graph of dielectric constant is not linear with respect to increasing frequency.
[image: graph of dielectric constant and frequency]
Polarization mechanism cannot keep with the frequency, and hence the dielectric constant abruptly drops. I get that.

But what/why are the kinks at the drop of atomic and electronic polarizations?

Comment: There can be multiple mechanisms involved, in such cases one can constructive and destructive interference. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_resonance

Comment: Just think about forced oscillation and resonance and the phase difference between driver and driven systems below and above the resonant frequency. You may find [Feynman - 31 The Origin of the Refractive Index](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_31.html), as well as the next chapter, of interest?